# Advanced AREL or just Rails Query for has_many through search by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, arel

```
#team.rb
has_many :players_teams
has_many :players, :through => :players_teams

#player.rb
has_many :players_teams
has_many :teams, :through => :players_teams
```

Given I have two star players named "Lisa" and "Bo", how would would I search the Team Model to find all the teams that have both Lisa and Bo on them, without looping through.  All the has_many through query examples assume I'm only looking for the  teams by one association attribute.  But I want to search by an array.  ["Lisa", "Bo"].

Comment: `Team.players.where("players.name IN (?)", ["Lisa", "Bo"])`

Comment: That would find teams with a player called Lisa or a player called Bob, not both.

Comment: @David that's absolutely right, and the reason I am asking the question.  All the examples of usage I've found do this, and will not produce the team or teams that have BOTH "Lisa" and "Bo" on them.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly ugly, but ought to do the job efficiently:

```
Team.where(:id => Player.where(:name => ["Lisa","Bob"]).
                         group(:team_id).
                         having("count(*) = 2").
                         pluck(:team_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a classic many to many relationship between players, teams and players_teams tables. Unfortunately, I could not find a pure SQL solution for this problem, but this one should be lightweight enough not to give your code any problems, even though I do not know if it will scale for huge DB:

```
Team.where(id: (PlayersTeams.where(player_id: Player.find_by_name("Lisa")).pluck(:team_id) & PlayersTeams.where(player_id: Player.find_by_name("Bob")).pluck(:team_id)))
```

Basically you get the teams for each player and find their intersections with ruby array. I would still like to see how the same thing can be done with pure SQL.

Comment: If I don't get a better answer this is probably it, but I'm dismayed to think my instinct was right, and that there IS no good way to do this.
WHich makes me wonder why I'm using a Joins Table in the first place.  I might as well keep an array column on the Teams that does bookkeeping on associated Players.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is the thing you are looking for:

```
ids = Player.where(name: ["Lisa", "Bob"]).pluck(:id)
Team.where(id: PlayersTeams.where(player_id: ids).group(:team_id).having("count(*) = ?", ids.count).pluck(:team_id))
```

One query, not counting the one that gives you player ids.